# Reopen commit window

Tags: tortoisegit

I often make multiple commits at once:

Changed files:

- `a.txt` (added)
- `b.txt` (modified)
- `c.txt` (deleted)

My typical workflow (jump to the end of the question for TLDR):

1. Open the repo in Explorer
2. Right-click somewhere, choose *Git commit -> <branch>*
3. Select `a.txt`, type message *Add information about letter A*
4. Commit
5. **Go back to the explorer Window.**
6. **Right-click somewhere, choose *Git commit -> <branch>***
7. Select `b.txt`, type message *Fix inaccurate information about letter B*
8. Commit
9. **Go back to the explorer Window.**
10. **Right-click somewhere, choose *Git commit -> <branch>***
11. Select `c.txt`, type message *Letter C has been deprecated and will be removed*
12. Commit
13. **Go back to the explorer Window.**
14. **Right-click somewhere, choose *Git commit -> <branch>***
15. Nothing left! Done.

Is there any possibility of having a *Reopen commit window after commit* or even *Reopen commit window after commit unless no changes left*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the TortoiseGit commit dialog open, click the down arrow on the right of the `Commit` button and choose the `ReCommit` option. This will leave the dialog open until you close it manually.

[image]

Comment: **I can't believe I missed that!**